# How to avoid linebreak when a long hyperlink / word is added in word on mac

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-word

I am trying to create a strictly formatted document. The problem is, when I try to add a long hyperlink, it formats it like below:

```
(320-330) Retrieved from: 
http://onelonglink.tld/samples?id=1gJPXv5wQbIC&pg=PA320&lpg=PA320&
dq=is+personality+biological+or+environmental?&source=bl&ots=rmMzyGABi&
sig=HiRb8kmiVa6UI2aigsl3FBN9evI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vDkAUp6bBMbNkgXbr4DACQ&
ved=0CCsQ6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=is%20personality%20biological%20or%20environmental%3F&
f=false
```

I do not want the link starting from a new line and breaking at points. I am using ms Word 2011 on mac.

Ideal result should be like this:

```
(320-330) Retrieved from: http://onelonglink.tld/samples?id=1gJPXv5wQbIC&
pg=PA320&lpg=PA320&dq=is+personality+biological+or+environmental?&source=bl&
ots=rmMzyGABi&sig=HiRb8kmiVa6UI2aigsl3FBN9evI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vDkAUp6bBMbNkgXbr4
DACQ&ved=0CCsQ6AEwADgK#v=onepageq=is%20personality%20biological%20or%20environment
al%3F&f=false
```

Comment: Do you mean you want it all on one line, no matter what?

Comment: I do not mind if it continues to next line. To show you the intended output, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use non breaking spaces (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd>) and hyphens (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>HYPHEN</kbd>) instead of regular spaces and hyphens.

Comment: Cheers mate, I would upvote you if I was allowed here.

Comment: Use command instead of the control key on a Mac.